# First user as administrator for MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am no smart and I run into this little issue. I have in mind an application I would like to create, an authorized system displaying what I have done during the day.
Only users I as the only administrator created will be allowed to log in to the system.

In order to make that application, I have to first insert me (administrator) into the database such that I can then continue to add new features into it. But MVC4's provided database (`myappname` as default)  can't be used directly for new member data insertion (especially the `webpages_Membership` table which needs encryption of user's password).

I am still too new to MVC4 to replace the defined database with a new one and start things from scratch.

Do you know what I have to do to insert `administrator` as the username with a password and defined values as a new member data into the defined table such that I can use the login page provided by the newly created MVC4 application ?

**UPDATE**
I am using VS2012, I turn on ASP.NET Configuration (Projects->Asp.Net Configuration) and follow the tutorial provided by the link in AdamB's post but it doesn't add the user into my database. 
I don't want to do this but I think right now I can only follow the `Register` link and register a new user (`administrator`) with password from there, only this way helps add a new member into my table. About the role, I directly add new rolenames into the table (webpages_Roles) and manually reference `UserId`, `RoleId` in appropriate tables in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that you created in ASP.NET Configuration is saved in its default database ASPNETDB.MDF. Click Show all files in the Solution explorer to see it. One way to save the user in your own database is to use Custom Membership Provider and Custom Role Provider. It also gives you control for everything in your authentication. Here's the link to [Custom Membership Provider](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-provider/), [Custom Role Provider](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-role-provider/), [Custom Membership User](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-user/). You could also try this one from MSDN [How to: Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx) and this one [Implementing your own RoleProvider and MembershipProvider in MVC 3](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am overwhelmed. I bookmarked them all, and sure will visit to work with them later (I am messing up the current simple MVC4 application only to learn about ASP+MVC4 ).

Answer (score 2):

Read this one, i think it would help you
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

Comment: :-D Cool! Seems like nothing is impossible! Thank you Adam B

Comment: I have created a user using `ASP.NET Configuration` but the user is not added into the database my application is using.

Comment: The user that you created in ASP.NET Configuration is saved in its default database ASPNETDB.MDF. Click Show all files in the Solution explorer to see it. If you want to save the user in your own database you can use Custom Membership Provider and Custom Role Provider.